# How i can get list of all the directions throughout the route in skmaps before starting navigation?

Tags: android, skmaps

I need to get information of all the turns that will be coming in navigation prior to starting navigation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the route has been calculated you can call [getAdviceList](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.0/com/skobbler/ngx/routing/SKRouteManager.html#getAdviceList(int,%20com.skobbler.ngx.SKMaps.SKDistanceUnitType)), something like:

```
SKRouteManager.getInstance().getAdviceList(routeInfo.getRouteID(),DISTANCE_UNIT_KILOMETER_METERS);
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Hi @Ando, How i can get audio advices with SKNavigationManager. If I start navigation with SKToolsNavigationManager, it gives me audio advices but not in case of  SKNavigationManager.
Thanks in advance

Comment: During navigation you'll get the audio advices in the SKNavigationListener - see http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec016

Comment: It does not give me audio advices with SKNavigationManager, I have also implemented advisor settings in onAllRoutesCompleted(), but still it is not working.

Comment: Or SKNavigationManager does not give audio advices in simulation mode?

Comment: The advices are received - you have to "play them"  - see the code inside MapActivity.java (in the demo project) - onSignalNewAdviceWithAudioFiles and onSignalNewAdviceWithInstruction